# 1and1 HTTPS redirect does not work but HTTP does

Tags: ssl, redirect, heroku, https

I have a web app running on Heroku and domain managed by 1und1 (German version of domain registrar 1and1). To make the app available via "example.com" I did the following:

1. Created www.example.com subdomain in 1und1.
2. Attached it to www.example.com.herokudns.com as described in Heroku's guides (CNAME www.example.com.herokudns.com).
3. Ordered SSL certs from 1und1 and used them to setup HTTPS on Heroku side.
4. Set up HTTP redirect example.com -> `https://www.example.com` to make top level domain to point to Heroku.

This all worked fine until I tried to get the app by `https://example.com` - Chrome shows me "This site can’t provide a secure connection" page with ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR.

cURL output:

```
#1.
curl https://example.com
curl: (35) Server aborted the SSL handshake

#2.
curl -vs example.de
Rebuilt URL to: example.de/
Trying <example.de 1und1 IP address here>...
TCP_NODELAY set
Connected to example.de (<example.de 1und1 IP address here>) port 80 (#0)
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.de
User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
Accept: */*

< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< Content-Length: 203
< Connection: keep-alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=15
< Date: Tue, 11 Jul 2017 14:19:30 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Location: http://www.example.de/
...

#3.
curl -vs https://example.de
Rebuilt URL to: https://example.de/
Trying <example.de 1und1 IP address here>...
TCP_NODELAY set
Connected to wavy.de (<example.de 1und1 IP address here>) port 443 (#0)
Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to example.de:-9838
Curl_http_done: called premature == 1
Closing connection 0
```

So, the question is: how can I set up HTTPS redirect with 1und1 and Heroku?

Comment: In my experience it can take several hours to take effect after installing the ssl certificate through 1and1.

Comment: @user1628733, thanks for your reply! Probably I should have mention it in the post, but I have installed SSL certs 2-3 weeks ago and HTTPS does work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering to my question.

After spending some time to google the issue out I found this article https://ubermotif.com/1and1-nightmare-bad-registrar-can-ruin-day. They faced the same issue. I decided to call to 1und1 support (they only offer calls no chats or email tickets). They told it is their issue, the GUI screwed up and they will put the dns settings to their DB by hands.
The issue is not solved yet, I'm waiting while dns changes will be applied/propagated.

Answer (score 0):

This type of error comes because of server or website. You should try following tips to fix the errors:

- Disable QUIC Protocol
- Remove or Modify Host file by removing bad programs or the website you searching for Clear SSL state by following steps:

  Start Menu > Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network and Sharing Center

  Click on Internet Options from the left button When internet properties dialog box will open, go in content tab and select 'Clear SSL' option.
- Check system time that it is matching with current time or not
- Check Firewall to see your website IP address has been blocked or not, and if blocked then remove from it